# jQuery only works on page refresh

Tags: angular

I am building an app in Angular2 and I have an accordion in jQuery.(I was building this for use in php but my boss now wants angular).

The accordion works fine on page load. However if I press the back button on the browser (going back to the page) it does not load again.

I have installed the typings for typescript and have declared `declare var $:any` underneath the import in my controller.

I have my jQuery inside this method.

```
    ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(document).ready(function($) {
      $('#accordion').find('.accordion-location-header').click(function(){
        //Expand or collapse this panel
        //Reset to default-up
        $('.accordion-location-header').not(this).each(function(index,el){
          $(el).find('i').removeClass('fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa-chevron-up');
        });
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down');
        //Hide the other panels
        $(".accordion-location-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
      });

      $('#accordion').find('.accordion-status-header').click(function(){
        //Expand or collapse this panel
        //Reset to default-up
        $('.accordion-status-header').not(this).each(function(index,el){
          $(el).find('i').removeClass('fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa-chevron-up');
        });
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down');
        //Hide the other panels
        $(".accordion-status-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: any fiddle ????

Comment: no I dont have, sorry

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has to do with document.ready()

Comment: ngAfterViewInit() ~== $(document).ready

Comment: can u try then ngAfterContentInit() ?

Comment: Did you try with out $(document).ready(function($) {});
Choose proper lifecycle hooks

Comment: I tried it without $document.ready and it does not load on page load

Comment: can you try ngAfterViewChecked(). As of I know  ngAfterViewInit()  triggers first time only, Try to use ngAfterViewChecked()  (it triggers for every changedetaection)